# how to print next line of the match string in python3 (If i give Tea , it should print next line too)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
BANL16fd1c9a1:file_exceptions jjimmy$ python3 search_cofee_records.py
Please enter an item name:-Tea
Description will be :- Tea
QUANTITY will be :- 500
BANL16fd1c9a1:file_exceptions jjimmy$


BANL16fd1c9a1:file_exceptions jjimmy$ cat search_cofee_records_for.py
def main():

    infile=open('coffee.txt','r')
    search=input("Please enter an item :-")

    for line in infile:
        line=line.rstrip('\n')

        if (line==search):
            print("Description:-",line)

    infile.close()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Boolean flag:

```
stop = False
def main():

    infile = open('coffee.txt','r')
    search = input("Please enter an item :-")

    for line in infile:
        line=line.rstrip('\n')

        if stop:
            print(line)
            break  ## or stop = False if you want to keep on checking for more matches

        if (line==search):
            print("Description:-",line)
            stop = True

    infile.close()
```

Essentially, I'm telling python that after the match has been found, I want to stop at the next line, which is why I use the `stop` flag, and then I `break` out of the loop to prevent every line afterwards from being `print`ed.

Comment: why are you stopping after the first match??

Comment: do I see the `break` statement, or do my eyes deceive me? =)

Comment: @lenik Just reread your comment again ... I thought the OP was only looking for one match. I'll edit my answer in case the OP wanted multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

I think it

```
 line=line.rstrip('\n')
```

should be before loop and you should use range for loop

```
def main():

    infile=open('coffee.txt','r')
    search=input("Please enter an item :-")
    lines=line.rstrip('\n')

    for i in range(len(lines)):

       if (lines[i]==search):
           print("Description:-",line)
           print(line[i+1])

    infile.close()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do just fine, unless you have a multi-gigabyte file that you don't want to load into the memory (most of the homeworks don't have such files =)

```
def main():
    search=input("Please enter an item :-")

    with open('coffee.txt') as infile :
        data = [i.strip() for i in infile.readlines()]

    for a,b in zip(data,data[1:] :
        if a == search :
            print("Description:-", a)
            print("QUANTITY will be :-", b)   # the next line

main()
```